# Regarding geotagged photos

Tags: photos, geolocation

I am using an iPhone 4 and I have many photos taken in different locations. Now I am planning to get a new iPhone 6. Can I sync these photos to my new phone? If so, can I see the locations on the new phone?

Answer (score 1):

The geolocation of each photo is stored inside the photo file itself, and goes with the photo when it is transferred to a computer or another device. This information will remain visible after being transferred onto your new phone.